# How find this value of $\prod_{1\le i<j\le n}(w^i-w^j)^2$

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, roots-of-unity

> give the positive integer number $n$, and $w=\cos{\dfrac{2\pi}{n}}+i\sin{\dfrac{2\pi}{n}}$ 
>   where $i^2=-1$

find the vaule

> $$\prod_{1\le i<j\le n}(w^i-w^j)^2$$

My try:note

> $$w^n=1$$
>   $$\prod_{1\le i<j\le n}(w^i-w^j)^2=\prod_{1\le i<j\le n}(w^i-w^j)(w^i-w^j)$$

and  I know this
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(1-w^i)=n$$
becasuse
$$1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}=(x-w)(x-w^2)\cdots (x-w^{n-1})$$
$$\prod_{1\le i<j\le n}(w^i-w^j)^2=\prod_{1\le i<j\le n}w^{2i}(1-w^{j-i})^{2}$$
Then I can't works,Thank you

Comment: How did you make the product a sum in your attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: First, find out the value of $$\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} (1-w^i)$$